# transform old httpGet to Pipeable operators

Tags: rxjs, angular6, angular7, ionic4

I have an abstract.service which does the CRUD operations. Now I am migrating from ionic 3 to ionic 4 but it seems that `rxjs` is updated and does not allow me to do this anymore:

```
httpGet(url, requestObject = new RequestObject, onSuccess = (resp, listData) => {}, onFail = (err) => {}) {
    let data;
    let headers;

    return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers, params: data})
        .map(response => response).catch(this.handleError).subscribe(
            (resp) => {
                if (!resp) resp = {items: []};
                if (requestObject.loader) this.globalService.onHideLoader.emit(requestObject.loaderId)

                onSuccess(resp, {});
                requestObject.onDone(resp);
            },
            (err) => {
                if(requestObject.loader) this.globalService.onHideLoader.emit(requestObject.loaderId);

                // Execute own errorHandling when response has no errorHandling
                // if(!requestObject.hasErrorHandling) this.onError(err);

                onFail(err);
                requestObject.onDone(err);
            }
        );
}
```

So How can I transform this pieve of code above to an example with `Pipable operators` here is what I have tried:

```
httpGet(url, requestObject = new RequestObject, onSuccess = (resp, listData) => {}, onFail = (err) => {}) {
    let data;
    let headers;

    return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers, params: data}).pipe(

        map(response => {
            if (!response) response = {items: []};
            if (requestObject.loader) this.globalService.onHideLoader.emit(requestObject.loaderId)

            onSuccess(response, {});
            requestObject.onDone(response);
        }),
        catchError(error => {
            this.handleError(error);
            if(requestObject.loader) this.globalService.onHideLoader.emit(requestObject.loaderId);

            // Execute own errorHandling when response has no errorHandling
            if(!requestObject.hasErrorHandling) this.onError(err);

            onFail(error);
            requestObject.onDone(error);
        })
    );
}
```

but at the `catchError` method it throws me this error:

`Argument of type '(error: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<void>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.`

Can somebody help me out convert the old method to the newer one?

Comment: The `.catch(this.handleError)` will just change to `catchError(this.handleError)`. `.subscribe(...)` can stay the way you had.

Comment: Subscription goes after `pipe()` so the chain should look like this `this.http.get().pipe(map(...), catchError(...)).subscribe()`

Comment: @martin thanks for helping me out that was the solution!

Comment: The `catchError` is fine inside the `pipe`. You just need to return the error as an Observable at some point (probably at the end). That the compilation error about.